# Как получить значение из запроса mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM album, competition
WHERE album.time_ >= competition.dateStart AND
album.time_ <= competition.dateEnd AND competition.end_ = 0
ORDER BY album.rating DESC LIMIT 3
```

Таблица `album` и `competition` имеют одинаковый столбец `id`.
Как получить `id` таблицы `album`?

Пробовал так:

```
$result['album']['id'];
```

И так:

```
$result[0]['id'];
```

И даже так:

```
$result['album.id'];
```

Но это неправильно. Подскажите, как?

Comment: выбирайте не select *, а явно перечисляйте все нужные поля. в том числе выбирайте id явно назначив ему другое имя (алиас) `select album.id as album_id from ...` и в php он будет с именем album_id

Comment: О, спасибо Вам! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8','root','');
    $query = "SELECT 
                a.time_,
                c.dateStart,
                c.dateEnd,
                c.end_,
                a.id AS album_id,
                c.id AS competition_id
              FROM album AS a, 
                competition AS c
              WHERE a.time_ >= c.dateStart 
                AND a.time_ <= c.dateEnd 
                AND c.end_ = 0
              ORDER BY a.rating DESC 
              LIMIT 3";
    $query=$db->prepare($query);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($result);
}catch(PDOException  $e ){
    echo "Error: ".$e;
}
```